# for..in loop returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object

consider this example

```js
let obj = {
    "minute": {
        "data": [
            {
                "s": [0],"values": {
                    "TV Web": {
                        "P": [0],
                        "S": [0]
                    }
                }
            },
            { },
        ],
        "product": ["Tom"]
    },
    "ads": {  },
}

for(let entry in obj){
console.log(obj[entry].product[0])
}
```

if you run the snippet it shows "TOM" and undefined.

How can I select only Tom? without having undefined?

Comment: `"ads": {  }` does not have a `product` property.

Comment: Your code actually shows an error. Check that. If you only want TOM, can you not check directly for the `minute` property? Are there more fields in your object?

Comment: @TusharShahi I already said the code will show two things the 'TOM' value and error message because ads doesn't have product.
My question is how can I solve this issue in JS

Comment: @JrichoLuck "*I already said the code will show two things the 'TOM' value and error message*" no, you said it shows `undefined`, not that it shows an error message.

Answer (score 1):

you can just directly access to that path `obj["minute"].product[0];`

if you want check in all of property, then you can skip `undefined` value

```js
for(let entry in obj){
  if (obj[entry].product){
    console.log(obj[entry].product[0]);
  }

  // or use ternari
  obj[entry].product && console.log(obj[entry].product[0]);

  // or use library like `lodash`
  console.log(lodash.get(obj[entry], "product[0]"));
}
```

Comment: after using lodash with this code  "console.log(lodash.get(obj[entry], "product[0]"));"
it shows an error saying product is not defined
in fact both of your solutions are showing the same error above.